# how to edit a line having IPv4 address using sed command

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to modify an ntp configuration file by adding some options to the line containing Ip addresses.
I have been trying it for so long using sed command, but no able to modify the line unless i don't know the IP addresses.
Let say, i have few lines as,
server 172.0.0.1
server 10.0.0.1

I need to add iburst option after the ip address.
I have tried command like.. `sed -e 's/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1.3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/ \1 iburst/g' ntp_file`
or `sed -e 's/^server +\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/server \1\.\2\.\3\ iburst/g'` ntp_file
but its not modifying the line. Any kind of suggestions would be really appriciated.

Comment: `but its not modifying the line` but it's doing something else or anything is happening? Do you get an error or any message? Note in basic regex, a backreference is with slashes. `sed 's/\(blabal\)/\1/'` - without \ the `(` `)`match literal characters.

Comment: `sed` does not "know" `\d`, use `[0-9]`. Also, you are using POSIX ERE syntax, use `-E` option (not `-e`).

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes its giving error as "sed: -e expression #1, char 62: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but when i am directly specifying the address, it working fine, its not working with the regex. tried with [0-9] as well.

Comment: `sed -E -i 's/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/ & iburst/g' ntp_file`? You also have `{1.3}` in the pattern, which is a typo.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i have tried this.. 'sed -e 's/([0-2][0-9][0-9]\)\.([0-2][0-9][0-9]\)\.([0-2][0-9][0-9]\)\.([0-2][0-9][0-9]\)/ & iburst/g' ntp_file', but it is giving error. The command you have given worked well. Now trying to understand the command you have given I am not good with the regex.

Comment: Please re-read the comment: ***`-E`, not `-e`***

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yeah sorry for this.. with -E as well the command i used was not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, now i understood the command you have given, thanks a ton :) .. marking  it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have used as  POSIX BRE cannot match the expected strings due to `\d` shorthand class that sed does not support, the misused dot inside a range quantifier and incorrect escaping of grouping and range quantifier delimiters.

You may use

```
sed -E -i 's/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/ & iburst/g' ntp_file
```

The POSIX ERE (enabled with the `-E` option) expression means to match

- `[0-9]{1,3}` - one to three digits
- `(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}` - three occurrences of a dot and one to three digits

The replacement pattern is  `& iburst` where `&` stands for the whole match.

The `g` flag replaces all occurrences.